# How do i extend Journal Items/Entries?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

```
class JournalItem(models.Model):
    _name = "account.move.line"
    _inherit = "account.move.line"

    test = fields.Char()
```

The code above doesn't work, be it on the Item model or the Entry model, the field never shows up after upgrading. The same method works fine on other models.

For context, the aim is to add the currency rate from res.currency along with conversions and the like.

**Update:**

While debugging a bit I noticed I get the following error when restarting the odoo service:

`TypeError: Model 'account.move.line' does not exist in registry. - - -`

The same error occurs for the account.move model.

Not sure what it means but I'll keep this post updated as I debug.

**Update:**

Fixed it, will make an answer explaining.

Comment: Maybe you forgot the import in `__init__.py` file.

Comment: @JuanSalcedo nope, everything's in order there. It all works on other models but not these two.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my custom module was being loaded in before the accounting module and thus could not find the model to extend it. Odd that it didn't raise an error while upgrading though.

To fix the issue I just had to add the accounting module as a dependency (in the manifest file) for the custom module.

From the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/module.html):

> **depends**
>
> ```
> Odoo modules which must be loaded before this one, either because this module uses features they create or because it alters resources they define.
>
> When a module is installed, all of its dependencies are installed before it. Likewise dependencies are loaded before a module is loaded.
> ```

I added the "account" module, though there are plenty of "account_*" modules in the code too, I assume these are like plugins and I won't be needing them.

Comment: In this case you should add the module/app introducing the model you're trying to extend. So `account` is the right one.